# Foreach loop doesn't output correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, lambda

I want to sort a csv file chronologically and this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    string bgColour = "";

    string[] col = line[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    csvList.Add(new CSVEntry() { date = DateTime.ParseExact(col[7], "dd/MM/yyyy", null) });

    var dates = csvList.OrderBy(x => x.date).Select(x => x.date);

    foreach (DateTime dueDate in dates)
    {
        if (dueDate == DateTime.Today)
        {
            // if due date is today, blue
            bgColour = "40FFFF";
        }

        else if (dueDate > DateTime.Today)
        {
            // if due date is not today yet, white
            bgColour = "FFFFFF";
        }

        else
        {
            // if due date has passed, yellow
            bgColour = "FFFF40";
        }
    }
}
```

However, it not only doesn't sort the file chronologically, but the colours for `dueDate` aren't showing accurately as well. Only `yellow` is showing.

I don't know much about `foreach` loop and am new to lambda, `List<T>` and LINQ.

**EDIT #1:**

I tried placing the `foreach` loop outside of the `for` loop like some of the solutions below, but the `bgColour` didn't seem to be working thereafter.

The below set of code is the continuation of what I want to execute:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    string[] col = line[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    ... (All the array and foreach codes from above...)

    if (col[1] == "Open")
    {
        if (col[9] == "DEFAULT")
        {
            sb1.AppendLine(new1 + bgColour + new2 + bgColour + new3);
            Label1.Text = sb1.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I'm not sure about this but, `bgColour` would then have to be before the `AppendLine`, right? And `AppendLine` is within the `for` loop. How do I work around like this, then?

**EDIT #2:**

I found another way for the `bgColour` to work with this set of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    string[] col = line[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] dates = col[7].ToString().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    Array.Sort(dates); // I know there's a problem here, please see below.

    foreach (string date in dates)
    {
        DateTime dueDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

        if (dueDate == DateTime.Today)
        {
            // if due date is today, blue
            bgColour = "40FFFF";
        }

        else if (dueDate > DateTime.Today)
        {
            // if due date is not today yet, white
            bgColour = "FFFFFF";
        }

        else
        {
            // if due date has passed, yellow
            bgColour = "FFFF40";
        }
    }

    if (col[1] == "Open")
    {
        if (col[9] == "DEFAULT")
        {
            sb1.AppendLine(new1 + bgColour + new2 + bgColour + new3);
            Label1.Text = sb1.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Based on some sources like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1fa262c8-e1d7-4db2-8e7e-b43ab705f6fa/sorting-datetime-array?forum=csharpgeneral), it states that `Array.Sort()` will work just fine `DateTime` array, so I decided to test it out but it didn't work for my code. However, this time, the `bgColour` is in place.

I know that my `foreach` loop is *still* in the `for` loop which is not supposed to be the case. It will be great if someone can help me get the `foreach` loop out. Explanations provided will be great as well.

Comment: Why do you use the foreach loop in the for loop ? Shouldn't be the foreach loop out of the for one ?

Comment: And what are you going to do with `bgColour`? Is this to be assigned to a property of `CSVEntry`?

Comment: @romain-aga Sorry, I didn't know about that.

Comment: @RenéVogt No, it isn't. It's just the background colour for one of the values in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing your sort and output for every line in the csv file. You need to build your whole csvList first and them run your sort and output.

```
string bgColour = "";

for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    string[] col = line[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    csvList.Add(new CSVEntry() { date = DateTime.ParseExact(col[7], "dd/MM/yyyy", null) });
}

var dates = csvList.OrderBy(x => x.date).Select(x => x.date);

foreach (DateTime dueDate in dates)
{
    if (dueDate == DateTime.Today)
    {
        // if due date is today, blue
        bgColour = "40FFFF";
    }

    else if (dueDate > DateTime.Today)
    {
        // if due date is not today yet, white
        bgColour = "FFFFFF";
    }

    else
    {
        // if due date has passed, yellow
        bgColour = "FFFF40";
    }
}
```

Comment: The `bgColour` doesn't work anymore? Even after I've placed it outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @user6234613 It depends on what you're doing with it. This code will overwrite the value of bhColour everytime the loop ocurrs. You need to do something with it.

Comment: I don't really have an idea on what I need to do. But I have edited my question to make myself clearer as to what I want. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    string bgColour = "";

    string[] col = line[i].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    csvList.Add(new CSVEntry() { date = DateTime.ParseExact(col[7], "dd/MM/yyyy", null) });
}

var dates = csvList.OrderBy(x => x.date).ToList();

foreach (DateTime dueDate in dates)
{
    if (dueDate == DateTime.Today)
    {
        // if due date is today, blue
        bgColour = "40FFFF";
    }

    else if (dueDate > DateTime.Today)
    {
        // if due date is not today yet, white
        bgColour = "FFFFFF";
    }

    else
    {
        // if due date has passed, yellow
        bgColour = "FFFF40";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe wrong, but I suppose you have something like this:

```
public class CSVEntry
{
    public string bgColor { get; set;}
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

So you can easily parse your CSV with this:

```
List<CSVEntry> csvList = line.Select(l => l.Split(',')).
              Select(col => {
                  CSVEntry entry = new CSVEntry { date = DateTime.ParseExact(col[7], "dd/MM/yyyy", null)};
                  if (entry.date == DateTime.Today)
                      date.bgColour = "40FFFF";
                  else if (entry.date > DateTime.Today)
                      date.bgColour = "FFFFFF";
                  else
                      date.bgColour = "FFFF40";
                  return entry;}).
              OrderBy(csventry => csventry.date).ToList();
```

Now you have a list of `CSVEntry` that is sorted by `date` and each entry has its `bgColor` corresponding to its date.

Comment: I do have a `CSVEntry` class. But at `date.bgColour`, it shows this error: `The name 'date' does not exist in the current context`.